# JavaScript aspect ratio calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to create a JavaScript conditional that uses the results of a function to display one part of the HTML code or another.

I found this code that calculates the aspect ratio on Gist:

```
/* euclidean GCD (feel free to use any other) */
function gcd(a,b) {if(b>a) {temp = a; a = b; b = temp} while(b!=0) {m=a%b; a=b; b=m;} return a;}

/* ratio is to get the gcd and divide each component by the gcd, then return a string with the typical colon-separated value */
function ratio(x,y) {c=gcd(x,y); return ""+(x/c)+":"+(y/c)}

/* eg: 
> ratio(320,240)
"4:3"
> ratio(360,240)
"3:2"
*/
```

What I want is to calculate the screen aspect ratio and if the screen ratio is 16:9 to run the following code:

```
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920X1080.jpg">
```

If the aspect ratio is 4:3 it should load this:

```
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1024X768.jpg">
```

This goes on for multiple screen resolutions.

Here is a JSBin link: http://jsbin.com/fedipuqasi/edit?html,js,output.

I did some research on StackOverflow but couldn't find any complete example and, unfortunately, it seems that my JavaScript skills got rusty.

Let me know if I need to provide additional details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work.

```js
function gcd(a, b) {
  if (b > a) {
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp
  }
  while (b != 0) {
    m = a % b;
    a = b;
    b = m;
  }
  return a;
}

/* ratio is to get the gcd and divide each component by the gcd, then return a string with the typical colon-separated value */
function ratio(x, y) {
  c = gcd(x, y);
  return "" + (x / c) + ":" + (y / c)
}

var ratio = ratio(screen.width, screen.height)
var imgContainer = document.querySelector('#img')

switch (ratio) {
  case "16:9":
    imgContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920X1080.jpg">'
    break
  case "4:3":
    imgContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1024X768.jpg">'
    break
  default:
    imgContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/other.jpg">'
    break    
}
```

```css
#img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#img img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="img">

</div>
```

Comment: Can we also add a case where if there's an aspect ratio that is not covered to just display one image instead of none?

Comment: It generates a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null. Any idea why?

Comment: I guess that it needs to be runned on page load?

Comment: @SporeDev yes. Just make sure that your script tag is just before the end of the `body` tag?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it. Placed it in the head by mistake. Thank you!

Comment: Next time, please provide valid javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The code you show is for displaying a ratio in a specific format, eg "4:3". You don't need to use that for testing.

A ratio is just a width divided by height, so just check against that result

```
var img = new Image();
var widescreen = 16/9; 
var standard = 4/3;

var userRatio = window.screen.width / window.screen.height;

if(userRatio == widescreen){
  img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/1920X1080.jpg';
} else if( userRatio == standard ){
  img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/1024X768.jpg';  
} else {
  //user using different screen resolution
  img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/other.jpg';  
}

document.body.appendChild(img);
```

And if you don't want to use a bunch of if statements you could store all the url's in an object where the ratio is the property names. And then use the calculated ratio to get the right url.

```
//Uses computed property names: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names
//If you are wanting to support older browsers, change this accordingly.
var ratioUrls = {
  [16/9]:"https://via.placeholder.com/1920X1080.jpg",
  [4/3]:"https://via.placeholder.com/1024X768.jpg"
}

var userRatio = window.screen.width / window.screen.height;

var img = new Image();
img.src = ratioUrls[userRatio] || "https://via.placeholder.com/other.jpg";
document.body..appendChild(img);
```

Comment: You are right about the format, it just seemed easier to understand with those formats (for me at least). Thank you for your answer, it's a great alternative using if/else instead of switch.